# Code coverage istanbuljs with callback function, like in removeEventListener

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-runner, istanbul

**istanbuljs** does not report the code coverage properly in case of callback function like in this example:

```js
obj.removeEventListener('unload', () => this.dispose());
```

test case:

```js
  it('dispose call removeEventListener', async() => {

    spyOn(obj, 'removeEventListener');

    obj.dispose();

    expect(obj['removeEventListener']).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(obj['removeEventListener']).toHaveBeenCalledWith('unload', jasmine.any(Function));
  });
```

Comment: what if you use `this.dispose().bind(this)` instead ?

Comment: I tried this but I got the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saved in a separated function the callback function to fix the istanbuljs code coverage report.

```js
obj.callDispose = () => { this.dispose() }; // obj.dispose();
obj.removeEventListener('unload', this.callDispose);  // obj.callDispose
```

test case:

```js
  it('dispose call removeEventListener', async() => {

    spyOn(obj, 'removeEventListener');

    obj.dispose();

    expect(obj['removeEventListener']).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(obj['removeEventListener']).toHaveBeenCalledWith('unload', obj.callDispose);
  });
```